# Solr search fieldType

Tags: solr

```
 <fieldType name="text_Pname_pl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_pl.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

My field look like this. I have field like full text search but with exacly search too .
Now its work like :

- News --> work fine only News (no news-19:00 or News_...)
- News* ---> work fine News_sport...
  -"News-sport*" ---> work fine all News-sport...

Problem now.

- cant find "News + sport" only like News* "News + s*" (not working )

  How to search string with space. I see that when i use Lowercase and space i have OR not AND.
  Thanks for Help.

EXAMPLE
my date : News, News + Sport, News17:15, News18:00

- When i search by "News" --> i want only News
- News1* --> must give me News17:15 And News18:00
- News give me all where is News in string.

Comment: A KeywordTokenizer does not split the word into any parts, and the LowercaseFilter should go after the tokenizer (the tokenizer should be the first part of the chain). Check the 'analysis' page under Solr admin to see how Solr processes the indexed text and the queried text for the field.

Comment: It'd be easier to split the requirements into separate fields for your examples; one field that would search for 'news' anywhere, and one that would search for only 'News' instead of trying to get different behaviors into the same field. I.e. search `exact:News` vs `somewhere:News` vs `prefix:News1`.

Comment: I think it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You're using KeywordTokenizerFactory, so the entire phrase will be considered a single token, as you can see [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer).

That's why you can't find if you search for words that are not in the same sequence of they are in your token/phrase.
If you search without '*', it will return only exact matched tokens.

Maybe you should use another tokenizer (like [StandardTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer) or [ClassicTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-ClassicTokenizer), for example) if you want to search for separated words.

Comment: Yes but i am looking for News and i want to see only News like in keyWord,
but i want to have option to finde News* or News + Sport*